# @yield, @section in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hello everyone I want to load `shopReq.blade.php` file in `master.blade.php` and I am successful in doing this. But when I load `modals.blade.php` file in `shopReq.blade.php` it does not included. Am I  doing something wrong here? Please help.

master.blade.php (in views/layouts):

```
<html>
   <body >
          @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

shopReq.blade.php (in views)

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<h1>Hello I am in shopReq.blade.php
@yield(content)
@endsection
```

modals.blade.php (in views)

```
@extends('shopReq')
@section('content')
<h1>Hello I am in modals.blade.php
@endsection
```

web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['web']], function()
    {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('home');
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @B.Desai No. Not error. I want `modals.blade.php` to be on `shopReq.blade.php`. But I am unsuccessful in doing this.

Comment: which `view` you are calling finally? In your question add route and view calling code. You have added `welcome` view code which is not the actual issue code in this case

Comment: replace ```@yield(content)``` with ```@yield('content')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the similar name.
You can't `yield('content')` inside a `section('content')` you will have to rename one of the sets.

So either change the yield in master and section in shopReq  or the yield in shopReq en the section in modal.

Answer (score 3):

replace `@yield(content)` on shopReq.blade.php with `@include('modals')`

modals.blade.php

```
<h1>Hello I am in modals.blade.php</h1>
```

on routes

```
return view('shopReq');
```

Answer (score 2):

As the user milo526 has said.

You have `@yield('content')` twice.

For any blade directive (yield, section, component...)

if there is a same name inside brackets it will be overwritten.

And now I have spot that you don't have the quotes ' ' on your second yield:

```
@yield(content)
```